# How to share my links to facebook twitter

Tags: android

I am new in android...i have given a task to do..i have provided an textView where my link is present..i have two buttons..on with named share in facebook and other with named share in twitter..what i have to do is when i click on any of the button at first the login page of each of the facebook or twitter is opened depending upon the button click..now when the user loged in..the link present in the textview is automatically shared on the facebook..so can anyone suggest me how to do this..if possible with example..

regards
Rahul

Comment: Well, you will have to look at the Facebook and Twitter SDKs for integrating this stuff. Look for examples on how to use these SDKs on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook Dev Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

[Twitter Dev Docs](http://dev.twitter.com/doc)

Do a little search, and you will get quite a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by getting Facebook and Twitter libraries to your project. Then make object of Twiiter and Facebook classes and perform the tasks with the help of that objects.

Comment: can you please tell me where i get this libraries..and how i can implemented it in my code..by simple example..if you dont mind